# Can I create a model for XML in Swagger UI?

Tags: xml, swagger, swagger-ui

I am looking into SwaggerUI as an option to document a ReST service. The service supports both XML and JSON formats.

I can see in the pets demo that you can specify the schema for your JSON objects using JSON Schema. However, I can't see a way to specify an XML schema, using XSD or DTD. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about XML models [here](http://swagger.io/specification/#xmlObject). I need it as well but I'm looking for a way to do this with annotations in Java.